# Do Java AWS Lambda best practices change when using GraalVM?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, quarkus, micronaut

From [AWS Lambda best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html):

> Minimize your deployment package size to its runtime necessities

> Minimize the complexity of your dependencies

I've been looking into frameworks such as [quarkus-amazon-lambda](https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda) and [MICRONAUT 2: AWS LAMBDA FUNCTIONS](https://micronaut.io/2020/08/31/micronaut-2-aws-lambda-functions/) and my understanding is they provide and encourage the use of "best of breed" libraries that are GraalVM friendly.

To date, my take on creating AWS Lambdas is keep dependencies to a minimum, keep the artifact small.

In the GraalVM native world, do the above quoted statements still hold true, or are we saying be more liberal with dependencies because cold start was the big issue?

**EDIT:**

From @jarmod in the comments:

> Also be aware that SnapStart may change the equation here.

It certainly has for me, today I made the decision to go with Plain Old Java and SnapStart. This solved the cold start problem and for me, that was the big driver for auditioning these frameworks. IMO AWS Lambdas are fairly simple functions and I don't feel the need to drag in deps.

Incidentally, looking at [LEVERAGING AWS LAMBDA SNAPSTART WITH THE MICRONAUT FRAMEWORK](https://micronaut.io/2022/11/28/leveraging-aws-lambda-snapstart-with-the-micronaut-framework/) SnapStart is comparable to native for "Hello World" but when starting the framework, native is ~twice as fast. It's quite anecdotal but from this I read small jars with SnapStart fast as native, big jars with SnapStart slower than native. This makes me lean towards sticking with Plain Old Java and sticking by AWS best practise.

Comment: Also be aware that [SnapStart](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-accelerate-your-lambda-functions-with-lambda-snapstart/) may change the equation here.

Comment: Great (and quick) follow-up on the SnapStart suggestion, Robert. Thanks for adding the additional context and results. I'm sure that will be helpful to others.

Comment: For information about Quarkus + Snapstart, make sure to read https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/2f9ff6f7d0b57afb480f9d364548179759a3b7a1/docs/src/main/asciidoc/amazon-snapstart.adoc

Comment: @geoand this question has gone quite stale, any chance of an answer from the Quarkus team?

Comment: @RobertBain what exactly are you trying to find out?

Comment: @geoand using `quarkus-amazon-lambda` are we still looking to "Minimize your deployment package size to its runtime necessities" and "Minimize the complexity of your dependencies" or does the much faster cold start mean we don't have to worry about this to the same extent?

Comment: Both I would say. `quarkus-amazon-lambda` should already be very minimal on its own, but Snapstart does mean that a larger dependency tree is less of an issue